# How to Kill Apache Camel Parent Thread after process complete successfully in Standalone Application?

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

I start Camel Main Standalone application using Unix Scheduler.

It initiates Routes; But as i have Thread.sleep(time) after context.start().

Now application first execute; whatsoever in routes; and when route finish processing(stop(), application still working and finishes when thread.sleep time over.

Any idea how to completely stop the standalone application after my route finish process?

Following is code snippet for reference:

```
    SimpleRegistry sr = new SimpleRegistry();
    sr.put("masterdata", dataSource);

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(sr);
    try {

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                 from("timer://alertstrigtimer?period=60s&repeatCount=1")....
                 from("etc").....
                 from("etc").....
                 from("etc").stop()
          }})
         context.start();
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("configure(): Exception in creationg flow:", e);
    }
```

Is any way within camel or may be in java to kill the thread after camel route stop all processing.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options, here some I would consider:

1. use [camel-main](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/main.html) and configure it to shut-down when a certain amount of the exchanges are done
2. use a [route policy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/route-policy.html) and shut-down the camel context according to your own rule